# Joomla content invisible after upgrade

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, database-restore

I have got an old joomla version running. Some 1.0.x. (I did not yet intend to upgrade this site but will do as soon as I find some time for doing so)
However I had to upgrade the outdated linux (Suse 10.1) on that server and installed ubuntu 12.04.

Then I copied all the files to the server, that I backed up before the OS upgrade. And I re-created the database and the user that Joomla was using to access the DB. I Imported the tables and data using phpMyAdmin which I used before to export the old data base.

I did that before with other (more modern versions of) Joomla installations. As far as I can see the database was recoverd fine and all the files were installed and are at a proper place. The Backoffice/Admin site works fine. All Links (an extenstion/component) and all content items are still there and just look fine. (Given it is a rather old version :)

But on the frontend site the content items are missing. Front page looks fine, menu looks fine but the content is empty.

Menu Items to components (old zoom gallery, weblinks component) work just right. Samples:

```
http://www.klecker.de/photo/index.php?option=com_weblinks&Itemid=52
http://www.klecker.de/photo/index.php?option=com_zoom&Itemid=26&catid=13
```

But "internal" links to content items - static and normal - don't work at all. Sample:

```
http://www.klecker.de/photo/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=121&Itemid=199
```

What could be wrong? What did I miss or overlook? Something related to the file system structure, which is slightly different between these two linux distributions and plesk versions? Or may different Versions of php5 or mysql cause some side effect?

Comment: it could very well be a PHP or MySQL version change. Joomla 1.0 was based on older version of PHP and MySQL, so if they are now new, there will be a lot of unrecognized functions.

Comment: Which function could that be?

Comment: well there have been lots of functions made with PHP 4 that are now deprecated with PHP 5. Out of all honesty, it might be better to start from scratch with Joomla 2.5.7

Comment: probably eregi() and split() would be some of the main issues. Rather than starting from scratch you could use mtw_migrator to migrate to 1.5, followed by sp upgrade or jupgrade to migrate the data again to 2.5. Have done this a few time and it works. Well usually anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you turn on your error debugging or let us know what the error is?

If you are on php 5.3 try the following. It worked for me on an archived (locked down) 1.0.15 site:

- Open /includes/Cache/Lite/Function.php
- Go to line 74, i.e. $arguments
  = func_get_args();
- Replace it with this:

  $arguments = func_get_args();
  $numargs = func_num_args();
  for($i=1; $i < $numargs; $i++)
  {
      $arguments[$i] = &$arguments[$i];
  }
- Save
- Test

5.3 support was not officially added to Joomla until version 1.5.15.

Comment: Thanks. You guys are great! stackoverflow is just great!